# Java class access modifier convention

Tags: java, coding-style

I got curious while I was looking at the Java exception code.

```java
public
class IllegalArgumentException extends RuntimeException {
 ...
```

```java
public
class NumberFormatException extends IllegalArgumentException {
 ...
```

Why doesn't write `public` in one line? Is it a convention?

But, other code write `public` in one line.

```java
public class RuntimeException extends Exception {
 ...
```

```java
public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer> {
 ...
```

I want to know

Comment: No convention I've ever seen. [`IllegalArgumentException` is not declared that way](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.java#L34). If you have decompiled the class from bytecode, it might be an artifact of the decompiler.

Comment: It's an outdated coding convention: see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8234335

Comment: I don't really know why this question was closed. Even if it's a convention thing, it's still a valid question to me.